# What line can touch the most chess squares?

Tags: geometry

If we draw a line using a ruler on an $8\times8$ chess board, what line can touch the most squares, how many? Is it the diagonal?

Comment: Do you consider the diagonal line to "touch" only the eight diagonal squares, or also the squares touching the diagonal squares? That is, is it sufficient for the line to intersect a single point of the square's boundary to "touch" it, or must it go into the interior as well?

Comment: I would think if you actually did some drawing the answer would present itself rather quickly.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this image which presents a line crossing through 15 squares on a chess board might demonstrate or at least help your understanding of the answer.

[image: Chess Board]

As you can see, a slightly offset diagonal line fully enters 15 squares in an alternating pattern. And yes, this is the line which touches the most chess squares (or at least one of them).

Comment: A line from one corner to the opposite corner would yield 22.